# PhpBB forum session issue

Tags: session, phpbb

Hi friends i have used `phpBB` for setting the forum for my site , but actually now we face a big problem ie, the `session` table in that.This table is filled with data like anything even we clear it , it become fill overnight it we do have a huge of visitors, `but is there any provision to disable the session recording` actually some where the `phpBB` checks for data in that table. we have been notified by the hosting company that `this query is a killer`!

```
SELECT * FROM `session`
```

This query slows down the site because of the huge amount of data so any help will much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each and every user visiting your Phpbb forum will always get its own session row in the session table. But these rows are removed as soon as the sessions expire. So the sessions table should never fill up, although **you might want to check your session time-out value in the Phpbb administrator**.

(If you are running this from a shared hosting account, it’s very hard to get any descent performance out of Phpbb as the software is very select query intensive and most shared hosting account don’t offer adequate MySql performance for it).